# Getting stains off of a glass top stove

Tags: cleaning

I have had a glass top stove for about three years now.  I have two spots that have stained black. The stains look like a patch of burnt food, however they are flat to the surface.  I have tried to use the white ceramic cook top stuff you can buy (to no avail).  I have tried to scrape it off with a razor (also to no avail, and this is why I know that it is flat to the surface of the stove).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, razor on glass is a *bad* idea.  I hope I don't have to explain why.  Just think about what you're doing there.

You definitely did the right thing by buying the cooktop cleaner (I assume you used Cerama-Bryte or some similar product), but that's only half the equation; if you just use a cloth or paper towel with that, you won't get good results.  There's a product called a ["Scrunge"](http://www.vileda.ca/en/scourers/ceran/) that's specifically designed for cleaning (scrubbing) glass cook tops.  Use that with the cleaning solution and it can clean almost anything off.

With a little bit of elbow grease (okay, a *lot* of elbow grease) I managed to clean off over a year of caked-on grease and charcoal around the burner rings that I was never able to get with the Cerama-Bryte alone.  I don't want this to sound like a product endorsement as there may be other, similar kinds of specialized "sponges" on the market, but this is the only one I know of that's safe to use on glass (i.e. won't scratch it like a scouring pad or those double-sided 3M sponges).

You can also try baking soda.  Make a concentrated paste (say 3 parts baking soda to 1 part water) and scrub it in as hard as you can.  This is often enough to clean by itself, but if that fails...

Finally, you can use the baking soda/vinegar track.  Use roughly equal parts of each but don't mix them in advance.  Instead, pour vinegar onto the stain and sprinkle on the baking soda afterward, or vice versa, and scrub right away while it's fizzing.  That will usually dissolve anything under it.

Comment: There is a special tool you can buy that implements a razor, and that is what I was talking about.  Cerama-Bryte is the stuff that I used.  Thanks for the tip on Scrunge, I will definitely be getting that.

Comment: I completely agree about the baking soda/ bicarbonate of soda and water suggestion . Just leave it for about 1/2 hour or so before you start scrubbing in order to give it a chance to work.

Comment: of course if it's burnt in badly enough, nothing will get rid of it.

Comment: I hate to make a fool of myself, but why is a razor on glass a bad idea? I use razor blades all the time to scrape off paint, plaster and other things stuck to window or sheet glass.

Comment: Glass is generally harder than steel.  Not stronger, but harder.  So glass would scratch steel, not steel scratching glass in most circumstances.

Comment: Speaking as someone coming to this site for the first time, it sounds incredibly arrogant and unhelpful to say "razor on glass is a bad idea. I hope I don't have to explain why." I and OP must be incredibly stupid not to know why.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ - Glass may indeed be scratched by steel if you're not careful. I've had a broken window wiper scrape a permanent arc on my windshield once, and they don't sell steel autmotive ice-scrapers for a reason (there are a few brass ones, tho.)

Comment: Generally you would use the razor blade parallel to the glass surface so it shouldn't scratch the glass. It sounds like that's how OP was doing it, so I don't see how it's obviously a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried melamine foam (e.g. Magic Erasers)? I use it to clean a lot of stuff, ceramics, stainless steel, glass (glass top stove and glassware) etc. Just soak the foam in water and rub it on the stain. It cleans by friction and won't scratch the surface.

Answer (score 1):

toilet bowl cleaner will also etch the glass. Also using a razor blade flat on the glass will NOT hurt it. How do you get a sticker off a window? Razor blade.

Answer (score -2):

toilet bowl cleaner and an SOS pad will take everything off.

Comment: Yes, it will take *everything* off - including the finish. Don't do this.