# How can I get these stains off my glass stove top?

Tags: cleaning, stove, glass

I have this glass stove with stains on it.

[image: white marks around heat elements]

I've tried baking soda, 15 minutes and a wet cloth but nothing happened. I don't even know what kind of stains they are! Could I please get some help?

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13222/27482

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting stains off of a glass top stove](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13222/getting-stains-off-of-a-glass-top-stove)

Comment: @anxioususer : You can try the stuff mentioned in the question that the others have linked to, but that was specifically a black stain, and you've tried baking soda (although not baking soda + vinegar).  As you clearly have a white stain, it's possible that it's different enough that those answers won't work.  If so, and they close this answer, just re-ask the question, and make sure to mention that you tried the answers in the other question without any luck.

Comment: One test - feel the surface… are the stains actually raised from the surface or are they really pits in it? The first might simply be limescale, the second would be acid damage to the surface itself.

Answer (score 2):

My stove regularly looks like this, and I can get sparkling clean by using Weismans(sp) glass cooktop cleaner and a green scrubby. Doesn't have the be Scotch-brite  brand, a dollar store scrubby will do. Don't use any water, just cleaner, scrubby and elbow grease. I do use a painters sanding block on top of the green scrubby to help with even pressure on the scrubby pad. 
I have also heard that Vim cream cleanser works as well. However I've found that cleaners specifically made for glass cook tops will buff off and leave your stove shiny and any other cleansers tend to leave your glass dull after wiping clean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Rubbing Alcohol and a nylon scouring pad? I use it to turn a black stove white all the time.

Comment: i don't think the idea here is to turn the stove white... are you talking about a glass stove top?

Comment: I've used it on both glass and metal stove tops. I suppose I should have said I've used it to bring a white stove top turned black from caked on grease and food back to white without removing paint or scratching the surface of the stove top.