Bubbles on glass stovetop
I have just purchased a glass top stove and the second time I used it there were white bubbles that look like they are inside the burner not something that can be scraped off, I used a stainless steel pan. Is there a way to get rid of these bubbles, and how do you prevent it from happening.

Can you add a photo of the bubbles? The [edit] function allows you to add one by using the photo icon in the menu bar, the pop-up window will guide you through.

It's highly improbable that what you are seeing is inside the glass, it's more likely that it's an optical illusion combined with the fact that you have to use different methods on a glass cooktop than on enamel or steel. Do your bubbles look like the ones in this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108875?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are a number of reasons for this. The most common is failure to remove overspills soon enough after cooking. That gives whatever spilled out of the pot or pan time to settle in and get hard and crusted on the glass surface.
https://guinco.com/cleaning-your-cooktop/#:~:text=your%20glass%20cooktop!,got%20cooked%20onto%20the%20surface
https://www.whirlpool.com/blog/kitchen/how-to-clean-a-glass-electric-
stovetop.html#:~:text=Baking%20soda%20is%20a%20powerful,to%20wipe%20away%20the%20paste.
There can also be micro-cracks on the glass surface of the stovetop. You may not see them at first but they will only get worse and usually arise from overheating the surface by prolonged cooking (left a pot on the stove and forgot about it?).
After you've cleaned the surface, if there's still obvious bubbles, try using a razor that's made for scraping glass--most Walmart-type or home center stores have them. Be careful not to scratch the surface of the stove; Hold the razor at an angle when trying to remove any burnt-on debris.
Lastly, bubbles can occur in the layers of the glass during its manufacture. Unfortunately, I'm not sure this is something you can repair on your own and may require the help of a professional.
https://www.meandmyglass.co.uk/blog/why-does-glass-have-air-bubbles-in-the-interlayer/#:~:text=Glass%20can%20have%20%E2%80%9Cseeds%E2%80%9D%20inside,in%20diameter%20are%20called%20blisters.
I've included some links for further reading. Hope this helps.
